# Choose rows that contain value inside string

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
                            Asp
2010-01-15 11:00:00    Moon0Sun
2010-01-19 15:00:00   Moon45Sun
2010-01-20 02:00:00   Moon50Sun
2010-02-01 05:00:00  Moon185Sun
2010-02-02 07:00:00  Moon140Sun
2010-02-02 15:00:00  Moon135Sun
2010-02-05 17:00:00   Moon0Sun
2010-02-08 05:00:00   Moon90Sun
2010-02-09 15:00:00   Moon50Sun
2010-02-10 02:00:00   Moon45Sun
```

I want to choose rows that contain zero as a number. If it is 50 or 140, it shouldn't be chosen.
Only rows like Moon0Sun.
How can I do it?

Comment: `df[df['Asp'].str.contains("0")]`

Comment: @jezrael, it returns Moon50Sun and Moon90Sun too. I need only Moon0Sun

Comment: So you need `df[df['Asp'].str.contains("\D0\D")]` ?

Comment: @jezrael, thank you, df[df['Asp'].str.contains("\D0\D")] works perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regex `\D0\D` for filter non number `\D`, `0` and no number `\D`:

```
df[df['Asp'].str.contains("\D0\D")
```

Another more general solution is get numbers and compare by `'0'` in [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df[df['Asp'].str.extract("(\d+)", expand=False).eq('0')]
```